# How to achieve inward folding after extrude

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

[image]

as shown on the right side of the picture

Comment: What is the left image?  The right image is a concave corner, so it isn't like the left image?  What do you mean by "inward folding", concave?

Comment: On the right is what I want to achieve.
How to create this -90-degree-angle  extrude quickly

Comment: thank you for your kind assistance，my friend

Answer (score 1):

I would go around it as to make it while Extrude you will need to place 3D Cursor in right place and Scale extrusion to it.

You can instead make it as such:

1. Add **Solidify** modifier with **Even Thickness**.
2. Apply it.
3. Go to **Edit Mode**.
4. Select needed faces.
5. <kbd>I</kbd> to **Inset**.
6. **Delete** created faces.

[image: steps]

Comment: After I tried your method and got the result I wanted，thank you my friend!

Comment: @YaoFq If my answer was helpful consider accepting it and upvoting.